# How to add product weight next to the price in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

Please I need the help.

I want to put product weight next to the price. I use Magento 1.7.

Thank you for your help.
Sorin

I find the answer:

edit view.phtml files
/app/design/frontend/default/deliciu/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

And add the cod:

```
<?php  $_weight = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getWeight()); if ($_weight < 1)
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight*1000,2) . " gr"; else
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight,2) . " kg"; echo $_weightstr; ?>
```

Comment: Nothing, if I had known what to try....

Comment: it's probably a layout thing. If you are familiar with HTML / CSS, edit the layout. You can then move the element containing the weight or style it to put it in the right position. If you're not familiar with HTML and CSS, follow some guides (this probably can be done with pure HTML), it's not too hard.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know what file to change :). You can help?

Comment: Not sure, I don't have a Magento installation at hand right now. Somewhere in the layout folder there should be a file like "product" or something in that direction.